# Coq can't discriminate between constructors for dependently typed inductive proposition

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I created this example type to demonstrate the problem I'm having:

```
Inductive foo : nat -> Prop :=
| foo_1 : forall n, foo n
| foo_2 : forall n, foo n.
```

Now clearly `foo_1 0 <> foo_2 0`, but I'm unable to prove this:

```
Lemma bar : foo_1 0 <> foo_2 0.
Proof. unfold not. intros H. discriminate H.
```

This returns the error

> Not a discriminable equality.

`inversion H` doesn't change the context at all. Oddly, if I change `foo` from `Prop` to `Type` then the proof goes through, but I can't do this in my actual code because it causes problems elsewhere.

How can I get this proof to go through? And why is this problematic in the first place?

Comment: @AntonTrunov sorry, that was a typo, fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: you can't.

Let's take a simpler example, where we also fail to prove a similar thing:

```
Inductive baz : Prop :=
| baz1 : baz
| baz2 : baz.

Goal baz1 <> baz2.
  intro H.
  Fail discriminate H.
Abort.
```

The above fails with the following error message:

> Error: Not a discriminable equality.

Now, let's try and find out where exactly `discriminate` fails.

First of all, let's take a detour and prove a very simple statement:

```
Goal false <> true.
  intro prf; discriminate.
Qed.
```

We can also prove the above goal by providing its proof term directly, instead of building it using tactics:

```
Goal false <> true.
  exact (fun prf : false = true =>
    eq_ind false (fun e : bool => if e then False else True) I true prf).
Qed.
```

The above is a simplified version of what the `discriminate` tactic builds.

Let's replace `false`, `true`, and `bool` in the proof term with `baz1`, `baz2`, `baz` correspondingly and see what happens:

```
Goal baz1 <> baz2.
  Fail exact (fun prf : baz1 = baz2 =>
    eq_ind baz1 (fun e : baz => if e then False else True) I baz2 prf).
Abort.
```

The above fails with the following:

> The command has indeed failed with message:
>   Incorrect elimination of `e` in the inductive type `baz`:
>   the return type has sort `Type` while it should be `Prop`.
>   Elimination of an inductive object of sort `Prop`
>   is not allowed on a predicate in sort `Type`
>   because proofs can be eliminated only to build proofs.

The reason of the error is this abstraction:

```
Fail Check (fun e : baz => if e then False else True).
```

The above produces the same error message.
And it's easy to see why. The abstraction's type is `baz -> Prop` and what's `baz -> Prop`'s type?

```
Check baz -> Prop.   (* baz -> Prop : Type *)
```

Maps from proofs of propositions to propositions live in `Type`, *not* in `Prop`! Otherwise it would cause universe inconsistency.

Our conclusion is that there is no way to prove the inequality, since to there is no way to break through `Prop` to do that -- you can't just use  rewriting (`baz1 = baz2`) to build a proof of `False`.

Another argument (I see it has been already proposed by @gallais): if it was possible to use some clever trick and do the proof staying within `Prop`, then the [proof irrelevance](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Logic.ProofIrrelevance.html) axiom would be inconsistent with Coq's logic:

```
Variable contra : baz1 <> baz2.
Axiom proof_irrelevance : forall (P:Prop) (p1 p2:P), p1 = p2.
Check contra (proof_irrelevance _ baz1 baz2).    (* False *)
```

But, it's known to be consistent, see [Coq's FAQ](https://coq.inria.fr/faq.html#htoc37).

You might want to look at the [Universes](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/Universes.html)
chapter of [CPDT](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/), section "The Prop Universe" specifically.

Answer (score 5):

The logic underlying Coq is compatible with the axiom of "proof irrelevance" which states that any two proofs of a given `Prop` are equal. As a consequence it is impossible to prove the statement you have formulated.

If you want to be able to discriminate between the two constructors, you need to make `foo` an inductive `Type` rather than `Prop`. `bar` is then accepted as a valid proof.

```
Inductive foo : nat -> Type :=
| foo_1 : forall n, foo n
| foo_2 : forall n, foo n.

Lemma bar : foo_1 0 <> foo_2 0.
Proof. unfold not. intros H. discriminate H. Qed.
```